# View.OnClickListener() greyed out even if the variable is declared?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

The `a.setOnClickListener` is not working and the `View.OnClickListener()` is greyed out even though the variable is declared. The `ImageView` is inside a pop up window. It's throwing an error:

> attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
> reference

```
public class MoodPopUp extends Activity {

ImageView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;

FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //-----------------------------User Interface--------------------------------------------------
    setContentView(R.layout.mood_picker_popup);

    DisplayMetrics  displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    
    //Pop Up Window Size
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*.8),(int)(height*.6));


    //-----------------------------Function--------------------------------------------------------

    //Pop Up Picker on Click
    a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Aemoji);
    
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = rootNode.getReference("Emoji");
            databaseReference.setValue("A");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my XML, it has the correct ID of Aemoji

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Aemoji"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/smiling"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what is actual problem

Comment: It's throwing an error when clicking the image "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: please also put the code where you using you ImageView then it will be easy to identify

Comment: Please edit your question add the code that produces that error. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

**TRY 1**:

if that didn't worked, try to set a `child` of your reference:

```
databaseReference = rootNode.getReference().child("Emoji");
```

**TRY2**:

The variable "a" is possibly null. You should debug into the function to see if it's actually found from the first statement in `setContentValues()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the exception, You're calling `setImageResource()` on a null `imageview` , However I don't see this function being called anywhere in the code You've given, Include the complete stack trace and the code where you call `setImageResource()`